# Question: AC Voltage and Current variables

Tags: voltage, current, ac, frequency, emf

So I know how alternating current is produced, but I'm curious to what determines the voltage and amount of current moving within the wire.

Does the **frequency** of the alternations give more voltage/current or does the **strength of the magnetic field** produce that? Or is it both?

Let's consider this energy as raw, **before** it's been transformed.

Comment: Are you talking about an AC generator?

Comment: If my memory works correct, in case of synchronous machines the voltage depends on the excitation current in the rotor.

Comment: What is raw energy?

Comment: @Andyaka sorry didn't think anyone would reply this quick. Generally speaking, yes, but I'm talking in a more practical sense.

Comment: @Chu as I stated, I referred to Raw energy as the by product of the generator with no load.

Answer (score 1):

Maxwell-Faraday's Law of induction says:

$$\varepsilon= -\frac{d\Phi_B}{dt}$$

Find out more on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction). The electromotive force \$\varepsilon\$ over a loop is given by the rate-of-change of the magnetic flux through that loop.

The amount of current depends on the situation and what is dissipating the generated power. A moving current through a loop will generate an opposite magnetic flux (Ampere's Law) to the one applied, which needs to be accounted for in Maxwell-Faraday's Law, and vice-versa. It basically uses the same principles as the self-inductance of an inductor.

Comment: This is basically what I was looking for. Thanks